# Mac Apple Script to get Signal/Noise of my Wifi

Tags: applescript

How do I get the Signal/Noise Value of my current Wifi using Apple Script?

System Information
Network
Wifi-Fi
Current Network Information:
Signal / Noise:

Answer (score 0):

For signal strength you can use:

```
set signal_strength to do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I|grep agrCtlRSSI|grep -o '\\-[0-9]*$'"
```

and for noise:

```
set signal_noise to do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I|grep agrCtlNoise|grep -o '\\-[0-9]*$'"
```